# Firebase connect to 3rd party service with pre-registered IP address

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an android POS app with Google firebase backend. Payments will be taken from our users via a payment gateway that only accepts connections via REST API from pre-registered IP's.

Can Google Firebase connect to 3rd party payment gateway via REST API, through registered IP address to process payment, and record result to the Database - or do we need to look for another backend service?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to integrate two quite big systems. I'm not sure advice on how to integrate the two is on topic for Stack Overflow. But a quick pointer: Firebase Database servers will never make a connection to your payment gateway, so IP protected access wouldn't help.

Comment: Thanks Frank. If a connection from firebase to the payment gateway can not be formed, I can not use firebase for my project. I think Amazon Lambda alongside with Amazon Dynamo DB will do the job perfectly though so i will shift my attention to that!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is unable to connect to 3rd party services with dedicated IP